# enrollment date 12 months before and after a specific date

Tags: date, sas, subset

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daP1m.png)I am trying to find persons by id who have continuous, 12 months enrollment before the hospitalization date and another 12 months after the hospitalization date. Each member will have one row. 
This is using claim database in US. Any help is appreciated. 
Example of the dataset:
ID Enr_date   End_Date     hosp_date
1  1/5/2004   1/6/2008     2/2/2006
2  .... and so on 
3
4
    id start_e end_e     date_h
1 1/1/2005 1/1/2006  2/8/2008
1 2/3/2006 4/5/2013
2 5/7/2005 8/8/2006  4/5/2007
2 1/1/2007 2/2/2012
3 5/9/2005 5/9/2007  1/1/2007
3 6/4/2008 7/7/2012

Comment: are you just looking fo: hosp-date - enr_date > 12 months and end_date - hosp_date > 12 months ?

Comment: Yes, but I want continuous enrollment with no interruption in service. Also some patients have multiple rows. So they could have different enrollment periods.

Comment: you need to ask your question better.  How does no interruption in service and multiple rows come into play?  if you can show a complete data set and a better description of your problem that may help

Comment: Please check the link at the top. A patient can have multiple enrollment rows as they may have coverage for 2 months and then a coverage gap. Then they may start another enrollment with different start and end date. What I meant by no interruption in service is the presence of coverage gap. If you take a look at the example I posted, only patient 2 should be included. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please type out your data and include it in the question, it gives something for people to work with. At this point to work with your data, I'd have to type it out.  You can use a self join via sql and on the dates to generate your solution. The enrolment problem is a common question. Search lexjansen.com or communities.sas.com for many similar questions and answers.

Comment: Your question and data don't seem well defined to me.  It seems that you have a start date and end date for coverage.  Is it correct in assuming that for the same user id multiple rows will be non overlapping?  Also, the Hospital date seems like the date of admission - will it always appear on on a record that shows coverage for that period?  What happens if you have two different HOSP dates for the same user during the same coverage period?

Answer (score 0):

assuming my last comments have answers there are many ways you can do this.  Starting out it may be difficult to get outer joins, cross joins etc working in a way that's easy to understand.  With a SAS macro we can break the problem down so it's easy to understand and do any debugging that may be necessary.  Here's one approach that may work for you:

```
%macro hdates;                                                                                                                        

 /* get number of hosp_dates    */                                                                                                                              
  proc sql noprint;                                                                                                                     
  select count(*) into: cnt                                                                                                             
  from date where hosp_date ne .;                                                                                                       
  quit;                                                                                                                                 

  %let cnt = &cnt;                                                                                                                      


  /* place hdates and ids into macro vars */                                                                                                                                  
  proc sql noprint;                                                                                                                     
  select  enrolid, hosp_date into: id_1 - :id_&cnt, : hdate_1 - :hdate_&cnt                                                             
  from date;                                                                                                                            
  quit;                                                                                                                                 

  proc delete data= hcov; run;                                                                                                          

  /* for each hdate id pair go through the dataset and test for 12 mo coverage                                                                                                                                 
  %do i = 1 %to &cnt;                                                                                                                   

  data new;                                                                                                                             
  set date;                                                                                                                             
  if (enrolid = &&id_&i) then do;                                                                                                       
      preDays = "&&hdate_&i"d - start_date ;                                                                                            
      postDays = end_date - "&&hdate_&i"d;                                                                                              
     if (preDays >= 365 and postDays >= 365) then output;                                                                              
  end;                                                                                                                                  
  run;                                                                                                                                  

  proc append base = hcov data=new;run;                                                                                                 

  %end;                                                                                                                                 






 %mend hdates;                                                                                                                         

 %hdates;
```

Answer (score 0):

I work in claims data and I think I understand what you are trying to ask.  I recommend making one table with the "condensed" enrollment ranges and another with the hospitalization dates.  Then you may merge them together and keep only those patients who meet your criteria.  The following code will condense the enrollment ranges (assuming good records):

```
PROC SORT DATA=dset_in; BY id enr_date end_date; RUN;

DATA enrollment (KEEP=id enroll_start enroll_stop);
    SET dset_in;
    FORMAT enroll_start enroll_stop DATE9.;
    BY id enr_date end_date;
    RETAIN enroll_start enroll_stop;
    IF first.id THEN DO;
        enroll_start=enr_date;
        enroll_stop=end_date;
    END;
    ELSE IF enr_date-enroll_stop <= 1 THEN enroll_stop=end_date;
    ELSE DO;
        OUTPUT;
        enroll_start=enr_date;
        enroll_stop=end_date;
    END;
    IF last.id THEN OUTPUT;
RUN;
```

Then this code will keep only those patients with a hospitalization and 365 days enrollment before and after.  If the hosp_claims dataset has more than 1 hospitalization per patient, sort then take the first obs per id after this step:

```
PROC SQL;
  CREATE TABLE hosp_enrolled AS
  SELECT DISTINCT a.id, a.hosp_dt, b.enroll_start, b.enroll_stop
  FROM hosp_claims AS a, enrollment AS b
  WHERE a.id=b.id AND b.enroll_start+365 <= a.hosp_dt <= enroll_stop-365;
QUIT;
```

Comment: Thank you Dave and DCR. Since I am dealing with claim database, the second answer fits best with my data, It worked! appreciate it